# Jordan Measure over Rational Numbers?

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose we wanted to define a version of the Jordan measure on $\mathbb Q^n$ - defining it the same way as it is defined over $\mathbb R$, but restricting ourselves to the space $\mathbb Q^n$ (or even, say, $F^n$ where $F$ is some field in between $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb R$). As an example of an application of this idea, this would allow us to generalize the notion that the determinant of a linear transformation measures change in volume to all subfields of $\mathbb R$. Let $m'$ be the "measure" that results from this definition. Obviously it wouldn't be a very useful measure unless we had $m'([0,1]^n) = 1$ - where of course, by $[0,1]^n$ I mean $( [0,1] \cap \mathbb Q)^n$.

Following the notation given in [the wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_measure), the key issue that could arise is that $m'^*([0,1]^n)$ somehow ends up being less than $1$ (which is exactly what happens when one tries to define the Lebesgue measure), or maybe it could happen that $m'_*([0,1]^n)>1$.

The only way that it is possible for that or some similar issue to happen is if $m'(S_1) > m'(S_2)$ for some simple sets $S_1 \subset S_2$. This, in turn, is only possible if well-definedness of the measure of a simple set breaks down, i.e., this paragraph

> One can show that this definition of the Jordan measure of S is independent of the representation of S as a finite union of disjoint rectangles. It is in the "rewriting" step that the assumption of rectangles being made of half-open intervals is used.

fails to hold true. I believe the proof of this fact would involve simply partitioning two different decompositions of $S$ into disjoint rectangles into one composition finer than both of them. It seems highly plausible to me that the same proof would work over the rationals, so I'm convinced the Jordan measure is still well-defined on $\mathbb Q^n$. Am I wrong?